# Selected Value not selected in a DropDownListFor of SelectList of SelectListItems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist, selectlistitem

The DropDownListFor is not selecting the SelectListItem that I am specifying should be selected. Unable to figure out why as all parameters appear to be correct.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class SchemesViewModel
{
    public int SchemeId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Schemes { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller (select list preparation):**

```
var schemes = schemeManager.GetUserSchemes(this.UserId);

var selectListItems = schemes.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Name, Selected = (x.Id == 2) });

var vm = new UserSchemesViewModel()
{
     Schemes = new SelectList(selectListItems, "Value", "Text", selectedValue: selectListItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Selected == true).Value)
};

return PartialView("_UserSchemes", vm);
```

**View:**

Note: This is where the select option with value of 2 is not selected!

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SchemeId, Model.Schemes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method. Internally the method build a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` using the `Value` of `Text` properties of you existing `SelectList` and sets the new `Selected` property based on the value of property you binding to.  You need to set the value of `SchemeId` before you pass the model to the view.

There is also no point creating a second identical `SelectList` from you first one (its just unnecessary extra overhead).

Modify your code to

```
public class SchemesViewModel
{
    public int SchemeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Schemes { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
var schemes = schemeManager.GetUserSchemes(this.UserId);
var selectListItems = schemes.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = x.Id.ToString(), 
    Text = x.Name
});
var vm = new UserSchemesViewModel()
{
    Schemes = selectListItems,
    SchemeId = 2
};
return PartialView("_UserSchemes", vm);
```

Now if one of your options has `value="2"` then that option will be selected when you first render the view.